# dynamically set value to the parameter of function attribute in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

I am facing problem while getting data list from data base using Linq DataContext

I am trying following code

> public class DBContextNew : DataContext
>       {
>
> ```
>     public static string StoreProcedureName = "";
>
>     [Function(Name = StoreProcedureName, IsComposable = false)]
>     public ISingleResult<T> getCustomerAll()
>     {
>
>         IExecuteResult objResult =
>           this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()));
>
>         ISingleResult<T> objresults =
>             (ISingleResult<T>)objResult.ReturnValue;
>         return objresults;
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```

but am getting error for

> [Function(Name = StoreProcedureName, IsComposable = false)]
>
> as An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof
>   expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

I wanted to pass value to Name attribute at run time.

Is it possible?

Please help.

Comment: It's not possible, Attributes parameters can not be passed in runtime

Comment: It is possible though the deep reflection. But You have to know that the reflection in runtime will cause the performance issues, so you have to do everything to live without it. Reflection is good when you do something on project startup or on some singleton inicialization.

Comment: Forget about passing dynamic data to the attribute, tell us what you will try to achive, and we will try to help you to fix it without attributes.

Comment: @Maris: I am trying to create a general function which returns table data from Stored Procedure. and that data is to be cast in given template type List i.e. T. for that i wanted to pass different Stored procedure name using variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
 public static string StoreProcedureName = "";
```

You need to make it a constant.

```
public const string StoreProcedureName = "";
```

The compiler tells you this in the error message (That it must be a constant expression).

Comment: thanks, but I wanted to assign value to StoreProcedureName  at run time so its not work for me.

Comment: @NileshNikumbh - I don't think you can pass them at runtime. I've experienced a similar problem,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't provide dynamic values (like the content of a variable) to an attribute declaration.

However you can change the values of an attribute at run-time:

```
public class TestAttribute : Attribute
{ public string Bar { get; set; } }

public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public string Foo()
    { return string.Empty; }
}
```

And then changing this value:

```
var method = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("Foo");
var attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TestAttribute)) as TestAttribute;
attribute.Bar = "Hello";
```

Please remember that attributes are shared across all instances of your class.

Comment: You have to remmember that this will cause the issues with multy-threading.

Answer (score 0):

Use the castle Dynamic proxy instead on simple attributes. Because to do it with attributes will force you to use the reflection in runtime to change something in attribute params. This way, like a `user1908061` adviced will cause 2 issues:

1) Performance issues. Calling in the runtime a stored procedures is very "heavy-weight" for the performance of your application
2) Multy-thread issue. Let's imagine that 2 threads call this codes with the interval of 10 ticks

```
var method = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("Foo");
var attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TestAttribute)) as TestAttribute;
attribute.Bar = "Hello";
```

Thread1 will change the attribute of `Bar` param to "Hello" in this time the Thread2 will access the same code and will change the `Bar` param to some other value, this will cause the problem. Let's look on it in the timeline:

```
 0 ticks - Thread1 started to work, accessed the property of TestAttribute and made the Bar param = "Hello"
 20 ticks - Thread2 started to work, accessed the property of TestAttribute and made the Bar param = "SomeOtherValue"
 40 ticks - You are expecting that you will call function with `Bar`=="Hello", but it's getting called with the `Bar`=="SomeOtherValue"
 60 ticks - Thread2 getting called with `Bar`=="SomeOtherValue"
```

So your Thread1 will get the wrong result.

So I would recommend to use CastleDynamicProxy to do what you want. With it you can run some code before the method and replace the result of method and also you can run some code after the method. This way will work in the runtime.

Also there is a technology - PostSharp will do the same but a little bit in another way. This one will work in the compile time.

Comment: Obviously you could add a lock in the property setter to avoid threading issues.

Comment: Yeap. This will solve the part of issues. But let's imagine that you have 1000000 threads running and trying to access this method, but they cant because the `Bar` is locked. This will bring even more problems. The proccess will be even more uncontrollable.